# When using the MIXED procedure in SPSS should set my 'time' variable as scale or categorical?

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, repeated-measures

I currently have a modelling issue, specifically in determining how to code the 'time' factor in my analysis, when the DV has already been adjusted for age.

My DV is a measure of child development, and it has already been adjusted for child age to produce a *z*-score. Conversion is not linear as the actual assessment varies depending on child age; scores are adjusted based on age of the child on day to the nearest fortnight.

Data on this measure were collected at 3 times (1 year, 3 years and 4.5 years of age).
This has been coded into SPSS as `Months` and `Visit`.

I therefore have 3 measures of 'time' in my data set:
1. `Age` – Child age at assessment (scaled to 2 decimal places),
2. `Months` – General age at which assessment was completed (i.e. 12, 36 and 54 months), and
3. `Visit` – coded as `0`, `1` and `2`.

I would like to use the `MIXED` procedure in SPSS to analyze the DV in relation to both 'time' and several other binary variables (e.g. attendance at preschool).
I have determined that using the `/REPEATED` command and an AR(1) covariance structure gives the best fit; however, I am not 100% sure how I should code time.

Should I use `Age`, `Months` or `Visit`?
If I use `Months` or `Visit`, should it be coded as `Scale` (i.e. the `WITH` command) or `Categorical` (`BY` command)? Remember that raw scores have already been adjusted for child age.

E.g. 1.

```
MIXED Z_Score BY Months  
  /FIXED=Months  
  /PRINT= SOLUTION TESTCOV  
  /REPEATED= Months | SUBJECT(UniqueID) COVTYPE(AR1).
```

E.g. 2.

```
MIXED Z_Score WITH Months  
  /FIXED=Months  
  /PRINT= SOLUTION TESTCOV  
  /REPEATED= Months | SUBJECT(UniqueID) COVTYPE(AR1).
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does AR1 even make sense if your time variable is a factor?!

Comment: I'm not sure.  At the moment I consider both Months and Visit to be Ordinal data types. If i wish to use either in the /REPEATED command then I need to choose a covtype... so i chose the one with the best fit.  Otherwise I could use /RANDOM